# Why is the Ajax heartbeat included in my cached frontend pages? Is it OK to get rid of it?

Tags: front-end, heartbeat-api

I recently thought I'd protect a WP site's `/wp-admin` folder with Apache's basic auth to provide a crude but somewhat effective additional layer of security (as a second line of defense should the WP install accidentally go out of date or an exploit emerge).

However when I did this, I immediately noticed that the site's cached front-end pages started showing the authentication dialog, too!

This appears to be because the Ajax heartbeat is being included in all the frontend pages:

```
var cnArgs = {"ajaxurl":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","hideEffect":"fade","onScroll":"no","onScrollOffset":"100","cookieName":"cookie_notice_accepted","cookieValue":"TRUE","cookieTime":"7862400",
"cookiePath":"\/","cookieDomain":".example.com","redirection":"","cache":"1"};
```

and

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var pvcArgsFrontend = {"mode":"js","requestURL":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","postID":"5","nonce":"e0785f90be"};
/* ]]> */
```

I understand the heartbeat's purpose in the backend and for users who are logged in, but it doesn't seem to make sense to have this in the public frontend (and it's obviously and needlessly messing with my password protecting my wp-admin directory.)

Can I safely unregister the script? Or is there a good reason why it is there?

Comment: I'm no expert but I've heard its not recommended to put pw on wp-admin. is it possible wp-cron is triggered by admin Ajax? you wouldn't want to disable that.  also have u tried while not logged in on front end?

Comment: @Joel yup, the references are in the non-logged-in version of the frontend pages. That's what seems so weird to me.

Comment: well not even sure if this is normal or not, but I'd check network -> XHR and see what data is being sent. could be a plugin rather than wp core.  p.s. sorry if this is obvious and you've already done this.

Comment: @JoelM that's indeed a good point about maybe a plugin causing this! Will check!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not okay to lock down or block access to `wp-admin` and/or it's sub-directories. Not only you already mentioned this is a crude method, it could and most likely will break the site, depending on its theme/plugins.

The reason is that some plugin or themes depend on either `admin-ajax.php` or `admin-post.php` to accomplish some tasks. That's why there are additional global variables in your source.

For example, the `pvcArgsFrontend` variable belongs to the [Post View Counter](https://github.com/wp-plugins/post-views-counter) plugin, which uses `admin-ajax.php` to update a post's view count. If you block `wp-admin`, you know what happens.